# Networkx Average shortest path with labels

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

I would like to calculate the average shortest path for nodes with the same label in a labeled graph. For instance, red is labeled A and black is labeled B.

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node('A', label = 'A')
G.add_node('B', label = 'B')
G.add_node('C', label = 'A')
G.add_node('D', label = 'B')
G.add_edges_from([('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'A')])
H = G.to_undirected()
```

[image: Labeled Graph]

Now i just want to calculate the average shortest path for A, based on this
[image: equation]

V_m are the vertices with the same label. n_{i,j} is the number of shortest path and 
d_{i,j} is the geodesic distance.

I would like to use Networkx to implement that. Starting to use the node attributes for the labeling.

I can read out the nodes with their labels with

```
graph_labels = (nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'label'))
```

Now i would just like to keep the key/value pair where the label is e.g. "A". So I can focus on the nodes with the same label. I hope that it is not to abstract but do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Select nodes by labels

```
def select_nodes_by_label(G, lab):
    return [node[0] for node in G.nodes(data='label') if node[1] == lab ]
```

This returns a list of nodes that we can use to get the shortest paths of all combinations.

```
from itertools import combinations

def avg_shortest_path_labeled_node(G, lab):
    sel_nodes = select_nodes_by_label(G,lab)
    V_m = len(sel_nodes)

    # collect all lengths of shortest paths from combinations of labeled nodes 
    sp_len = [len(nx.shortest_path(G,c[0], c[1]))  for c in combinations(sel_nodes,2)]
    n = len(sp_len)
    return sum(sp_len)/(n) * 1/(V_m * (V_m - 1))
```

### Test

```
avg_shortest_path_labeled_node(G,'A')
```

[out]:

```
1.5
```

Is it the result that you expect? It might be interesting to test this function on a more complex graph.